# Can't suggest edits to tag wikis on meta; excerpts not consistently shown on tags page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, tag-wikis

It appears that there is no ability to suggest edits to tag wikis on meta (at least, I can't).  It also appears that several tags that have excerpts are not showing anything on the tags page (e.g., [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mess with meta tag wikis -- we plan to export all the common, standard meta tag wikis from meta.so.

(There might be an exception for topic specific, special per-site meta tags but these are quite rare in my experience.)

I definitely encourage anyone interested to assist in editing the *main site* tag wikis, however, particularly the page 1 tags.. please!

Comment: I saw some mention on meta.SO of exporting the tag wikis from meta.SO, at least for the status-* tags, and most or all of the tags I looked at here have wikis already (probably exported), but only a few of the tags on the first page here have anything showing up, even if they've got a wiki already.

Comment: What are "page 1 tags"?

Comment: @isaac that's a bug, I told Sam to fix it. We'll try to push out all the meta tags tonight.

Comment: @isaac see if it looks better now. still a few rough edges but should be improved.

Comment: @Jeff: In terms of displaying the excerpts, it does seem better (I didn't check every tag, but spot-checking tags with no excerpt shown didn't seem to find any hidden excerpts now).

Comment: @Asaf: I think "page 1 tags" refers to those tags that appear on the first page when you click on "TAGS" (below "MATHEMATICS" and to the right of "QUESTIONS").

Comment: sorry @asaf I neglected to answer, it's the tags on this page http://math.stackexchange.com/tags

Comment: Hmm. I'll try to do my part in the set theoretic tags sometime this weekend.

Comment: Wow. It has been a month. I did **not** do my part. I guess that's why I'm lazy. ;-)

Comment: @asaf we'll be docking your salary accordingly... (wish I could help, but I am beyond useless at math)

Comment: @Jeff: It's fine. As long as the scholarship from the university keeps me fueled with booze, I don't really need extra money. I wish I could promise to do it soon, but I just know it's unlikely. Especially with all the work I am finally doing in actual mathematics. Huzzah.

Comment: @Asaf: I presume from your remark that you'd prefer that your "salary" be in booze form? ;)

Comment: @J.M.: This is the penultimate solution, though. It was best if my regular bar would also sponsor me directly. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I just unlocked editing of tag wikis on all metas. My plan is to keep the "big" ones in sync provided they did not diverge.

If the community decides to put a community "spin" on any of the meta tag wikis, that is fine in my opinion.

Clearly you should (and can) edit any tag wikis for the blank tag wikis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Time to get cracking...